# wp_insert_post() database changes

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to repeat all sql requests that occurs during wp_insert_post() execution. Also I need to create categories (also create new if not exists) and custom fields. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you can find a number of helpful questions and you can accomplish it very easily. Go research, code, test and let us know if you come across any difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to the Wordpress documentation for the [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#source) you will find there section called "source" - you can see there all that is done when function `wp_insert_post()` is executed.

You see it's a lot of things. For most cases it is much better to use the built in Wordpress functions.